# Questions about EOF and EOL

Tags: c++, windows, stdio

I am trying to understand EOF and EOL, and how C++ iostream actually works.

While taking the the input through `getchar()` or `getche()` into a `char` variable, I found that if I write lines like:

```
char a;
a =  getche();  // it returns char '\r' if pressed enter
a =  getchar(); // it returns char '\n' if pressed enter
```

Why these values?

1. What actually makes C++ think that we have run out of input (**i.e is it always `'\n'` that makes C++ think that it's at the end of its input?**).
2. While reading/writing a file that has some string sentences ending with `'\n'`  then what happens if lines end with a `NULL` character, which also represents an end-of-line?

Could you explain all these briefly with examples?

Comment: I don't see iostreams being used in your examples. What is this question about?

Comment: Note that `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char` value.  It can return any valid `char` value plus EOF which is distinct from every valid `char` value (and is negative).  Assigning the result of `getchar()` to a `char` is a rookie mistake.

Comment: This isn't anything to do with iostreams.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> While taking the the input through `getchar()` or `getche()` in `char`
>   variable, I found that if I write line like:
>
> ```
> char a; a = getche(); // it returns char '\r' if pressed enter
> a = getchar();        // it returns char '\n' if pressed enter
> ```

Firstly, `getche` is a POSIX function from `conio.h` that is non-standard and deprecated in all major toolchains.

It's an unbuffered, non-formatted read operation. When your input stream uses `\r\n` for line endings (common on Windows), then you are reading that first character `\r`.

When you then perform `getchar()`, you're getting the second character, `\n`. This is a C function, too.

The rest of my answer will be about C++.

> What actually makes c++ think that we are not gonna provide any input
>   (i.e its always \n that makes c++ think that its end of input?).

The buffered I/O functions tend to delimit reads by `\n`, yes. There is a parameter to `std::getline` which allows you to change this delimiter:

```
std::istream& std::getline(std::istream& is, std::string& str);
std::istream& std::getline(std::istream& is, std::string& str, char delim);
```

But this is just a delimiter. You may consider that it signifies "End Of Line", but it's certainly not "End Of File".

> While reading / writing a file (that has some string sentences ending
>   with \n . then what if lines end with null char , which also
>   represents end of string?).

Null characters don't matter.

The only time null characters are a problem is in C-style `char` buffer strings with no accompanying length information. The only way to *determine* the string's length becomes searching for the *terminating* null character (see: `strlen`), which is problematic if there are arbitrary other null characters scattered throughout the useful part of the data.

If you're passing around a pointer to a `char` array *and* its size as an `int`, then it can contain as many null characters as you like.

When reading characters from a stream, in C *or* C++, the function you use tells you how many characters were read. So, even if some of them were null characters, it doesn't matter. You can handle them as you see fit.

> what char represents end of line while writing / what char represents
>   end of input of line while reading?

I didn't quite understand this question, but I'll wrap up my answer by briefly describing End Of File.

Historically, files had a physical character `\004` (`^D`) that sat at the end of its contents and represented End Of File.

Nowadays this physical character isn't used in this manner, but the internals of the OS and File System will use varying mechanisms to inform your application that there is [no more input](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file). The C functions will return the macro `EOF`, and the C++ objects have a state flag that you can check.

The detail of precisely how this works is abstracted away from you; you shouldn't have to care about it.

Interestingly, to end input in a Linux console, it's still `^D` that you press on the keyboard.

---

I hope that this has helped you somewhat. Your question wasn't particularly clear, but the above is intended to be a brief description of EOL and EOF in C++.

I can recommend [these books and resources](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources) for further reading.

Comment: Just a nit, but what system had `\004` which signaled EOF in a file.  Windows used `\032` (`^Z`), and Unix files have always been transparent, passing all characters up to the application.  (The Unix tty driver does use `\004`, by default at least, to force the buffer up to the application, without the `\004`.  If there's nothing in the buffer, the application reads 0 char's, and most applications will treat this as an end of file.  But it only occurs with the tty, and unlike a real EOF, the next read will work as usual, even if no more characters have been written.)

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing C and C++.

The C++ way is [like this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/):

```
std :: string input;
while (std :: getline (input_stream, input)) {
     // Do stuff
}
```

`std::getline` returns `input_stream` which casts to boolean false when the input runs out or something else fails. Here, "runs out" means "encounters EOF" or some analogous condition.

You can also do

```
std :: string input;
while (std :: getline (input_stream, input, delimiter)) {
     // Do stuff
}
```

if the default `'\n'` is not the right line terminator.

[EOF is a special ASCII value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) which is historical, relates to early printer protocols and terminal hacks, and now matters only when you use `getchar` or other such antiques.

`'\n'` is the UNIX standard end-of-line character. Microsoft uses `"\r\n"` which is two instructions to a printer: move the head to be beginning of the line, and move the paper up a row. UNIX decided that there was no reason that this has to continue into the world of non-printed files and dropped the `'\r'`

Comment: Actually, UNIX's ancestors still required this carriage-return behaviour, [but abstracted it for programmer convenience](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#History).

Answer (score 0):

getchar and getche should get one character at a time. There should be no concept of the "end of a line." If you end your line with a NULL character, you should get that back as the character you read.

When the end of the file is read, you will get the special EOF macro as your return value. Match that to detect the end of the file. If you get a '\n' or a NULL, you can parse that as is appropriate to your file (i.e. handle as end of a line of text).

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/getchar/

(not sure i've ever used this one)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kswce429(v=vs.80).aspx